# Hybridization in Light of Resonance

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, hybridization, resonance

According to this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ns4Py96Bkn8&NR=1

[image]

1) Is this true? (You might recall I asked a similar question about $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization implying $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization for all directly linked atoms a while back, but I couldn't remember my prof's exact wording). I *think* this YouTube video is saying the same thing my prof said.

2) Does this rule imply that both the oxygens in the below diagram are $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized? Each is connected to an $\ce{sp^2}$ carbon atom. Each has lone pair(s).

[image]

3) Even if we didn't know that the rule existed, we should still know that both oxygens are $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized because of the following resonance possibility, correct?

[image]

---

ETA:

If the above is true then this doesn't make sense:

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the OCS on the blackboard?  You might want to post this as a separate question, making it concise and clear.

Comment: I mean the chlorate ion on the blackboard.

Comment: The molecule is pyramidal, so the chlorine cannot be described as being $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized.  Nor can the oxygen as it is presumably (based on the resonance structures) some mix of $\ce{sp^2}$ and $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridization.

Comment: I agree. I'll have to see my prof to get his exact wording on this issue. And if necessary I'll counter with the chlorate ion example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Is this true?

It's more or less true in the cases were hybridization methods \ techniques work.  For example, when the hybridization of water is discussed it is often said that the central oxygen is more or less $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized and therefor the two lone pairs on oxygen are in (roughly) $\ce{sp^3}$ orbitals.  Current thinking based on photoelectron spectral data suggests that, instead of this traditional view, one lone pair appears to be in an orbital that is predominantly $\ce{P}$ and the other in an orbital that is predominantly $\ce{S}$.  So hybridization models don't always give the correct answer.  I'm not sure what the hybridization of an atom with a lone pair that's attached to a double bond really is.  But it is probably OK to say what the teacher said in an introductory class in order to keep things simple for a while.

> 2) Does this rule imply that both the oxygens in the below diagram are
>   sp2 hybridized?

Assuming that the traditional hybridization approach is applicable here (e.g. is the ester oxygen behaving like water or is it "traditionally" $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized?) then yes, both oxygens are roughly $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized.  Remember, hybridization is not a step function.  There are hybridization indices between 2 and 3.

> 3) Even if we didn't know that the rule existed, we should still know
>   that both oxygens are sp2 hybridized because of the following
>   resonance possibility, correct?

Some data on esters suggests that the $\ce{C-O-C}$ angle is around 115 degrees.  Somewhat between 109 degrees ($\ce{sp^3}$) and 120 degrees ($\ce{sp^2}$).  And maybe an intermediate hybridization is what we should expect based on the resonance structures for an ester.

Comment: I love that first statement! I just want to add, that an $\ce{sp^2}$ center cann $\pi$ interact with any $\ce{sp^{x<2}}$ center.