# Aromaticity of Caffeine

Tags: aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

[image]

In the Caffeine molecule, is aromaticity confined only to the 5 membered ring? The entire molecule is planar and the 6 membered ring also seems to have 6π electrons.
The entire molecule has 10π electrons.(inside)

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/54268/102629

Comment: This question does not mention anything about the 6 membered ring except that it is planar

Comment: This link has an answer: [Caffeine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140102193955/http://quantum.esu.edu/~scady/Chem495/keskineva.pdf).

Comment: You should condense the content of that link into an answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The 6 membered ring is also a part of its aromaticity.

This can be better understood by considering the Zwitterion of Caffeine.

[image]

The entire molecule is planar, conjugated and has 10π electrons(4n+2)

Reference:[Slides by Nevina Keskineva](https://web.archive.org/web/20140102193955/http://quantum.esu.edu/%7Escady/Chem495/keskineva.pdf)